# Why my flask app works on localhost but doesn't work on aws EB after adding flask jwt

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, jwt, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a flask application which has Flask JWT inside for authentication. **It worked on localhost and Ngrok.** However, after I deployed the app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, it showed me an **Internal Server Error**. I don't get the error after I removed all the JWT related code and uploaded it again. I don't know why JWT is causing the error.

This is the jwt I included in the flask app

```
from flask_jwt_extended import (
JWTManager, jwt_required, create_access_token,
get_jwt_identity
```

The log on aws says

> the file application.py cannot be loaded as a python module

Please click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wabbz.png) to see the full error log

In my requirements.txt, I have included

```
Flask==1.0.2
jwt==0.5.4
Flask-JWT-Extended==3.13.0
PyJWT==1.6.4
```

I have also tried deploying to Heroku and that didn't work either.

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements contain two packages that both contain a module named `jwt` (`jwt` and `PyJWT`). Apparently on EC2 and Heroku the wrong one ends up being used (by `Flask-JWT-Extended`, which expects `PyJWT`).

Comment: I found it weird to have two JWT. I uninstalled them as well as the extended one and then reinstalled the extended one. It is working! Thanks!